# Unity3D game throwing errors only on target Android device. What is the best way to debug this errors?

Tags: c#, android, debugging, unity-game-engine

My Unity3D Android game is throwing errors exclusively when running on Android devices (after long gameplay). There is no error on standalone nor editor play.

What is the best way to debug this errors (find script/line?)

Errors like this:

```
ArgumentNullException: Argument cannot be null
Parameter name: key
Internal error. Trying to destroy object that is already released to pool. 
IndexOutOfRangeException: Array index is out of range
```

My game is using GPS for gameplay (no it is not another Pokemon clone;)) so I need to test it outside.

Connecting profiler via wifi makes the game run incredibly slow and I can't test it in that way.

Comment: It said `Internal error`, this is probably a bug.

Comment: You could try to put a try-catch block around all routines that you think could cause such an error and store the stack trace. Its very time consuming though. And not guaranteed to bring any results. But maybe you get a hint on what exactly is going wrong. Given of course that this is an exception at all.